# how to run django server seccond time I have install a django successfully

Tags: django, python-2.7

how to run django server seccond time I have install a django successfully in my localhost with cmd yesterday  now i want to run the django again so how can i run now.than you in advantge.

Comment: `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: here is my folder structure  C:\Users\Admin\kumar\kumar

Comment: go to the path in the project where `manage.py` exists and then run the command

Comment: not able to understant what you say

Comment: hello nsing, I think Usman means this: 1: search a file called manage.py at your server/project. This file contains the commands you can use to run the server again. So calling the command "runserver" from this file would start your server. The command would be: $PATH_TO_DIR_CONTAINING_YOUR_manage.py(path) manage.py(file) runserver(command). Best of luck!